# How can I solve the problem of slow query on the last ten pages

Tags: postgresql, kaminari

I created 10 million pieces of data in the nfts table of the local postgres database, paged the data, inverted the data according to the id, 10 pieces of data per page, and queried the first ten pages and the last ten pages of data. Each page was queried ten times. Here is the average time required.

The following is the time required for data query of the first ten pages, in milliseconds

```
20.5
12.9
15.6
13.6
13.9
12.9
12.5
13.1
12.2
13.7
```

The following is the time required for data query on the last ten pages, in seconds

```
2.377
2.385
2.389
2.399
2.388
2.385
2.394
2.374
2.399
2.377
```

My paging uses gem "kaminari".The usage is as follows`NFT.order(:id).page(params[:page]).per(10)`
To display the index page. I added index to id.
The query statement on the back end is:

```
Started GET "/nfts?page=999992" for ::1 at 2023-03-16 09:10:03 +0800
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Pluck (1.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by NftsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"page"=>"999992", "nft"=>{}}
  NFT Count (785.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 1 AS one FROM "nfts" ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 9999910]]
  ↳ app/controllers/nfts_controller.rb:10:in `index'
  NFT Load (1670.2ms)  SELECT "nfts".* FROM "nfts" ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 9999910]]
  ↳ app/controllers/nfts_controller.rb:12:in `index'
Completed 200 OK in 2480ms (Views: 9.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2466.1ms | Allocations: 14400)
```

How can I solve the problem of slow query on the last ten pages.

Attach the time required for each page of the first ten pages and the last ten pages
The following is the time required for data query on each page of the first ten pages, in milliseconds

```
1:[77ms, 13ms, 10ms, 11ms, 17ms, 11ms, 17ms, 16ms, 12ms, 21ms]
2.[16ms, 11ms, 12ms, 10ms, 11ms, 11ms, 10ms, 18ms, 11ms, 19ms]
3.[23ms, 14ms, 16ms, 13ms, 23ms, 18ms, 12ms, 15ms, 12ms, 10ms]
4.[15ms, 16ms, 16ms, 11ms, 11ms, 12ms, 10ms, 10ms, 15ms, 20ms]
5.[22ms, 11ms, 11ms, 11ms, 12ms, 17ms, 12ms, 17ms, 16ms, 10ms]
6.[13ms, 19ms, 19ms, 10ms, 16ms, 11ms, 10ms, 10ms, 10ms, 11ms]
7.[11ms, 11ms, 20ms, 10ms, 16ms, 12ms, 9ms, 14ms, 11ms, 11ms]
8.[11ms, 16ms, 16ms, 11ms, 11ms, 9ms, 12ms, 12ms, 22ms, 11ms]
9.[12ms, 10ms, 15ms, 9ms, 14ms ,10ms, 12ms, 15ms, 11ms, 14ms]
10.[10ms, 23ms, 10ms, 11ms, 17ms, 11ms, 15ms, 10ms, 21ms, 9ms]
```

The following is the time required for data query on each page of the last ten pages, in seconds

```
-1.[2.37s, 2.42s, 2.41s, 2.39s, 2.35s, 2.37s, 2.31s, 2.34s, 2.37s, 2.44s]
-2.[2.36s, 2.40s, 2.43s, 2.39s, 2.40s, 2.47s, 2.36s, 2.36s, 2.33s, 2.35s]
-3.[2.34s, 2.37s, 2.40s, 2.41s, 2.41s, 2.37s, 2.52s, 2.37s, 2.35s, 2.35s]
-4.[2.35s, 2.38s, 2.43s, 2.42s, 2.38s, 2.38s, 2.46s, 2.38s, 2.39s, 2.42s]
-5.[2.37s, 2.37s, 2.37s, 2.46s, 2.38s, 2.40s, 2.35s, 2.40s, 2.40s, 2.38s]
-6.[2.43s, 2.35s, 2.40s, 2.41s, 2.36s, 2.38s, 2.39s, 2.33s, 2.41s, 2.39s]
-7.[2.38s, 2.36s, 2.39s, 2.37s, 2.42s, 2.40s, 2.50s, 2.37s, 2.37s, 2.38s]
-8.[2.39s, 2.38s, 2.37s, 2.39s, 2.34s, 2.37s, 2.37s, 2.35s, 2.40s, 2.38s]
-9.[2.38s, 2.41s, 2.38s, 2.38s, 2.38s, 2.39s, 2.43s, 2.41s, 2.41s, 2.42s]
-10.[2.37s, 2.40s, 2.33s, 2.37s, 2.38s, 2.37s, 2.40s, 2.38s, 2.39s, 2.38s]
```

Comment: Check this article: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/

Comment: Most people will probably have no idea what "kaminari" is.  What is the query that gets issued to PostgreSQL?  What is the plan for that query?

Comment: Thank you. I am reading this article. I have added the explanation of Kaminari, the query statements in postgres, and the purpose of doing so

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query statements to query

```
select * from foo where ID > [huge] order by ID limit 100
```

Comment: How to solve the paging problem